# Finding dimension of a Matrix subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following question [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXKTa.png) to prove it's a subspace I did the following:

Since it will form  the equations and will give the solution in terms of x1,x2..xn.As x1,x2..xn are solutions then Ax1=0,similarly Ax2 till Axn will be zero.

Now for some scalars c1,c2...cn

A(c1x1+c2x2..+cnxn) = c1.0+c2.0...cn.0=0. So its a subspace.

But I am unable to figure out how to find the dimension for the same subspace.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking the space defined. It is a subset of $\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $x$ is fixed. The correct proof would be to consider $A_1, .., A_k$ in $W$, scalars $c_1, .., c_k$, and note that

$(c_1A_1+...+c_kA_k)x = c_1A_1x+...+c_kA_kx = 0$

As for the dimension, $m(n-1)$. Write the product $Ax$ explicitly, it becomes quite clear.

Comment: Perfect!!Thank you for correcting me.But I didn't get the dimension part.Could you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Intersection of $m$ independant hyperplanes in a space of dimention $m\times n$